# Sequence of DNA

Tags: dna, sequence-analysis, nucleic-acids

While giving an amateur reading to DNA. I was stuck within the first few lines:

Refined resolution of the structure of DNA, based on X-ray crystallography of short synthetic pieces of DNA, has shown that there is a considerable variance of the helical structure of DNA, based on the sequence. **For example, a 200-bp piece of DNA can run as if it were more than 1000 bp on an acrylamide gel if it has the right sequence. The double helix is not the same uniform structure.**

What does this highlighted portion mean?

Comment: Please provide a source for your quotation. The English is slightly strange, especially the last sentence. I think I know what it means, but an answer would be more useful if the context were provided. Your title should probably be something like "The effect of base composition on the structure of DNA", if this is indeed what it is about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DNA sequence is what we call a string of nucleotides in the DNA polymer, such as `GATTACA`, representing a chemical structure wherein each letter ("G", "A", "T", "T", "A", "C", "A") represents a nucleotide that has a chemical bond to the next nucleotide. Possible nucleotides in DNA are adenine, guanine, thymine, and cytosine, e.g. A, G, T, C (you may also see such terms as thymidine, thymosine etc. depending on what piece of the DNA molecule you're talking about). What such a sequence implies for double-stranded DNA is that those nucleotides are then hydrogen-bonded to another "reverse complement" sequence, which for every nucleotide in the first sequence has a "C" for every G, a "A" for every T, a "G" for every C, and a "T" for every A. One way of representing this would be as follows:

```
GATTACA
|||||||
CTAATGT
```

Where `|` represents a hydrogen bond between the two strands of DNA at each nucleotide. A single-stranded DNA however would not have the H-bonds or the (lower) complement sequence.

Altogether, this is what is implied by DNA "sequence", though normally we only write `GATTACA` for simplicity.

What your quote means is that `GATTACA` can have a different behavior in a polyacrylamide gel than `GGGGGGG` or `ATATATA` or `CCGGCCG`, or any number of other 7-nucleotide DNA polymers. This has to do with the shape of the different nucleotides, each of which has a distinct chemical structure:

[image]

Some of the nucleotides force the DNA polymer molecule to take on different shapes, or to be stiffer or more flexible, because of their underlying chemical shape.

A polyacrylamide gel is basically a big tangle of polyacrylamide molecules and bonds. So think of DNA moving through it like trying to drag a rope through a forest. A very long rope will tangle more than a short one and will take more effort/time to pull through the trees. However, a rope of the same length that has a different structure (maybe it has lots of knots tied in it, or it is stiff rather than flexible) may also be harder to pull through the forest, even though it's not any longer.

Comment: I like your analogy in the last paragraph. I might borrow it...

Comment: @MattDMo thanks! it is my go-to for any kind of electrophoresis. There's a professor at UNM, maybe emeritus now (I forget her name... just saw a talk one time) whose whole thing is to think of all the tiny molecular stuff as happening on a spatial scale that is similar to our environments ("walk into a cell. what do you see?"). I think she's very right that that makes a lot of this stuff click in human brains.

Answer (score 0):

It means what it says.

DNA runs through a gel at a speed which is due to its shape, which is mostly determined by its size.  What it's saying is that certain sequences alter the shape of the DNA so much that its passage through a gel resembles that of a much longer piece with a more standard helical shape.

Comment: Does it mean this: that a 200bp DNA can run at slower speed as if it is a 1000bp DNA, if it's sequence is altered in a certain way.    WHAT DOES THE RIGHT SEQUENCE MEAN IN THE SECOND LAST SENTENCE.?

Comment: @Arjun Tilak It means that some sequences can make the DNA take on different shapes like sequences with lots of G can form G quadruplex structures. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-quadruplex#:~:text=In%20molecular%20biology%2C%20G-quadruplex,one%2C%20two%20or%20four%20strands.

Comment: @ArjunTilak Avoid using strings of all-caps like that. It is perceived as "shouting" on the internet and can come across as quite rude.

Comment: @BryanKrause ok sir!! I am new at this site,will keep in mind!